# Group numeric variable using if else statement

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a variable (V7) in dataset (total observation is 137) range from 0 to 100, I would like to create a new variable (V12) which it group the variable (V7) into 3 groups with 75-100,60-74, 0-59. I use

```
if(data$V7>="75"){
  V12 <- 1
} else {
  if(data$V7>="60"){
    V12 <- 2
  } else {
    V12 <- 3
  }
}
```

but I get
    Warning messages:
    1: In if (data$V7 >= "75") { :
      the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
    2: In if (data$V7 >= "60") { :
      the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Anyone could help me on this matter? Thanks!

Comment: What programming language is this?  You should tag your question with the language in use.

Comment: jlhoward, thanks! I manage to group it to the intervals, but how do I create the new variable for this group? Because I need it for further statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question properly, you want to make three groups from a dataframe.

## Let's assume you have 2 vectors. Let's create some random numbers and make your data

```
require(stats)
V7 <- runif(137, min=0, max=110)
V1 <- runif(137, min=0, max=10)
data<-data.frame(V1,V7)
```

## class 75-100

```
g1 = data[data$V7 >= 75  & data$V7 <= 100,]
g1$V7
```

## class 60-74

```
g2=data[data$V7 >= 60 & data$V7 <= 74,]
g2$V7
```

## class 0-59

```
g3 =data[data$V7 >= 0 & data$V7 <= 59,]
g3$V7
```

Comment: Hi ToNoy, thanks! The dataset is actually with total of 11 variables, one of the variable are range from 0 - 100, I want to group them into 3 intervals and create a new variable for it. Your solution is very useful for me as later I need this knowledge to run simulation as well. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
set.seed(1)      # so this is reproducible
df     <- data.frame(V7=sample(0:100,50))
df$V12 <- 0
df$V12 <- findInterval(df$V7,c(0,60,75,100))
```

Comment: jlhoward, I get it. Thank you very much! :)